# Debugging Outlook with command line arguments with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, outlook, command-line-arguments

I am trying to access command line arguments from an Outlook (2007) add-in. When I run outlook from the command line:

`"D:\Apps\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select outlook:calendar`

then I can access the arguments fine with GetCommandLineArg() (and outlook shows the calendar by default, as expected with this command line argument). However, when adding the same argument to Debug -> Command Line Arguments in Visual Studio (2017) (with the start action being "Start project"), outlook does not show the calendar on startup, AND GetCommandLineArg() only returns the outlook executable path.

How do I pass command line arguments to Outlook when debugging an Outlook add-in in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that changing the Visual Studio start action from "start project" to "start external program" (pointing it to outlook) resolves the issue; the command line parameters are passed on and can be accessed from an add-in.

Are there any disadvantages to using "start external program" vs "start project" when debugging an outlook add-in in visual studio?

Comment: Glad to know that it has been resolved, thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer. In addition, my understanding is that they are two different debug ways. Start external program: it indicates that a specific program should be started when the application is debugged. For example, like the class library project. Start project: It means that the .exe could be started like Console or windows apps.